# Is it possible to mix SSR/SSG and CSR with Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I would like to benefit from both SSG & CSR advantages for the same page depending of the visitor origin.

- For a direct visit to page 1 **or** page 2 I would love to use SSG to render the page and optimize loading time & SEO.
- If a user is going from page 1 **to** page 2, I would like to render page 2 with CSR so I would be able to animate the transition.

Is that possible with Next.js?

[image: SSG & CSR combination]

Answer (score 2):

Next.js will automatically deal with this - if a page can be rendered statically, then navigating to it will be near instantaneous. This is due to preloading that happens in the background.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the preloading happening in the background?

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding the red CSR arrow in your sketch

**Yes, it is possible by using the `<Link>` component**, which is actually the intended way of linking between pages in Next.js and used instead of `<a>` tags.

> It is the primary way to navigate between routes in Next.js. ~ [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link)

The [`<Link>` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link) provides **prefetching** and **client-side navigation** between routes. If in your example, you have placed a `<Link>` from Page1 to Page2...

- ...[Prefetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#2-prefetching) means: as soon as on Page1 the link to Page2 comes into the user's viewport, Page2 will be downloaded in the background
- ...[Client-side navigation](https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/navigate-between-pages/client-side) means: if the user clicks on the link to Page2, the page transition will be performed client-side using JavaScript
  -> you can use page transitions e.g. with `framer-motion` as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVU3JD6qOBo&t=218s&ab_channel=HamedBahram)

### Regarding the two black SSG arrows in your sketch

If you would call Page2 directly via the browser address bar, you would get the page directly from the server **as SSG**.

Of course this will only take effect, if you're not in an active user session of your app where Page2 is already in the [local cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#router-cache) (because you've visited it before or seen the `<Link>` on Page1, which triggers the prefetch). In that case client-side navigation would be done to provide a better user experience.

---

##### p.s.: you don't have to worry about loading time & SEO even for CSR pages

Even if you do CSR in Next.js, the page is pre-rendered (i.e. delivered via SSR/SSG). This is described in the docs of both [Pages](https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering) and [App](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#how-are-client-components-rendered) Router.

You are by default not using real CSR when specifying `"use client"`, but instead CSR + SSR/SSG (pre-rendering). To use CSR without pre-rendering, you have to [actively disable it](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#skipping-ssr).

The small downside of client-side rendering in Next.js is [neither loading time nor SEO, but instead the time until the client component is interactive](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering), because a process called hydration is therefor necessary.

Hydration is a bit cumbersome, because it consists of the JavaScript checking that the DOM (from the server's HTML) is in the expected state (which the client's JavaScript would produce) and if not, modify ("reconcile") it. It then needs to attach event handlers. ~ [Next.js Docs, see "Then, on the client:"](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#full-page-load)